# How to display rows as columns?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have data as shown below

```
Column1 Column2    Column3
F1           D1         S1
F2           D2         S2
```

I want this to be displayed as:

```
F1            F2
D1            D2
S1            S2
```

THank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Take Transpose, print it. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at pivot tables, something like:

```
WITH pvt AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT col1
           ,col2
           ,col3
    FROM table
  ) AS pvt_select
  PIVOT (
    min(col1)
    FOR col2 IN (
      valueInCell
      ,anotherValueInCell
      ,andSoOn
    )
  ) AS pvt_columns

SELECT * FROM pvt
```

Check the documentation on this topic as well. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

I'm using pivots a lot because of vertical designed tables. (pk, fk, property, value)-like tables. Depending on what your needs are you can also choose for `max()` and `avg()` as PIVOT operator.